# Is there any online fatwa QA website for Shafi Fiqh?

Tags: fiqh, fatwa, internet

Salam,
I have been browsing the internet for Shafii scholars who have their own QA fatwa website but unforgettably only found one or two inactive ones. is there any online fatwa QA website for Shafi Fiqh?

Answer (score 1):

How about [this site](http://islamqa.org/category/shafii), else you may seek for scholars with an own website. 
I don't know of any who are still alive or active.

An other option is asking on a site about the Shafi'i view only (like on islamweb.net ...)

Answer (score 0):

The following site is active and reliable: [ShafiiFiqh.com](http://www.shafiifiqh.com).

Comment: This site is inactive... send them a question a never got a reply and it has been a month since